# how do I use puppeteer to click 'I agree' button for google cookies

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to open google translate and enter text into the detect language field, and then return the result in English. However, I am falling at the first hurdle as the button below won't let me through. I know I can use page.click() but I cannot find a button ID and do not know how to click it otherwise.

[screenshot of the button I need to click, and the results of inspecting it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcziA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to select the button [using an XPath expression](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) with `contains()` and [then click it](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandleclickoptions):

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//button[contains(., 'I agree')]");
if (!button) throw new Error("button not found");
await button.click();
```